# is sewing knitting embroidery crochet etc allowed during sefirah

Tags: clothing, sefirat-ha-omer

During sefirah are we allowed to knit, sew crochet, embroider etc.

we are not supposed to buy certain clothing articles and I was wondering if doing these things would be a problem even if we are not making elaborate things but small things like knitting doll blankets etc

Answer (score 2):

See Shulchan Aruch [Orach Chayim 493](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2265): I have not found any prohibition or minhag to not buy certain clothing articles. May be that such a rule is for the days preceding Tish'a Beav ([siman 551, 7-8](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2908)).
One of the Minhag in Sefira is that women do not work after the sunset([493, 4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2267)).